# when a floated image is given inside a div, the div's height is not increased? Why?

Tags: css, css-float

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="C:\Users\Ragul\Desktop\my resume html\images.png">
    </div>
   </div>

.container {
 width:100%;
}

.logo img {
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

How does the float work in the above case?. 
As next step, I want to fit the logo inside the div for navigation purpose. How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

> when you use floated image,it takes out of the normal flow of the document.

So,

> 1) use : `overflow:hidden`

```
.container {
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

> 2)use `:after`

```
.container:after {
   contant:'';
   display:block;
   clear:both;
}
```

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.logo img {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When an element is floated it is taken out of the flow of a website. This means in your case the `.container` element will not use the `.logo img` element height to determine it's own height.

The solution to this is to clear the child elements float. This involves adding an element after the floated element and adding `clear:both`. A popular method of doing this these days it to use a pseudo element. In your example it would look like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="C:\Users\Ragul\Desktop\my resume html\images.png">
  </div>
 </div>

.container {
 width:100%;
}

.logo img {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* clear float */
.container:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```